# Python get class but exclude inherited attributes and methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Hi I have 2 classes a Model and Parent Class

```
ModelMaster:
  myvar: string = "one"
  def myfun():
    # do stuff

Model(ModelMaster):
  first: string = "hello"
  second: int = 123
```

Modelmaster contains functions that all models should use and attributes

When using the Model as purely a model I want to get the Model instance including all of its attributes but I dont want to see anything that was inherited from ModelMaster

Is there someway to get, from instance of Model, a copy of that model with just the attributes of that class that has all parent attributes and methods removed.

It seems like there would be something built into python3 to do this, rather than writing this myself

anyone have any ideas?

thanks,
Simon

Comment: *When using the Model as purely a model* Well when does that happen?  Looks like you *want* to define two separate and independent classes and ond then a third one which inherits from both. Maybe, since you haven't described the use case for which you need to tweak OO

Comment: "Just the instance attributes"  would be `instance.__dict__` - perhaps you could transplant that dict onto an instance of a class that doesn't inherit from `ModelMaster`, although this strikes me as being an extremely weird thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new class with `Model.__dict__` passed to the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) constructor, but not `Model`'s base class:

```
PureModel = type('PureModel', (), dict(Model.__dict__))
```

so that:

```
print(PureModel().first)
```

outputs:

```
hello
```

and that `PureModel().myvar` would result in:

```
AttributeError: 'PureModel' object has no attribute 'myvar'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to use

```
annotations = self.__annotations__
keys = {}
for annotation in annotations:
    name = annotation
    type = annotations[annotation]
    data = self.__getattribute__(annotation)
keys.append({"name":name, "type":type, "data":data})
```

this method can exist in any class in the inheritance tree and it will only return the attributes for the top level class

I'm still hoping that someone might come up with a cleaner version but this works for me